# div Блок имеет свой контент, но его высота 0

Tags: html, css, scss

Доброго дня! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Имеется блок для слайдера, он имеет контент, но его высота все равно равна нулю, если не задать ее фиксированно, но тогда не получится сделать нормально адаптив. Почему так происходит? и как можно решить такую проблему?

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;


.slide-prev {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 43px;
  left: 5%;
  top: rem(140px);
}

.slide-next {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 43px;
  right: 5%;
  top: rem(140px);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
}
}
```

```html
<!--slider -->
          <aside class="slider  clearfix">
            <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="img/slider/slide-prev.png" class="slide-prev"></a>
            <a href="#" class="slide"><img src="img/slider/slider-1.png" class="slide__img"></a>
            <a href="#" class="next"><img src="img/slider/slide-next.png" class="slide-next"></a>
          </aside>
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, о каком именно блоке идет речь? Блок .slider имеет высоту по контенту, в данном случае 24px.

Comment: @Mikl да блок slider. до на странице он имеет высоту  = 0. и clearfix не помогает..

Comment: Если выполнить ваш код, то высота .slider равна 24px. Возможно, его родительский блок сжимается до нуля или в коде есть еще стили переопределяющие его высоту и не вошедшие сюда.

Comment: @Mikl Родительский блок - контент, он высотой на всю страницу, там все норм. В стилях не пойму что его может ограничивать, если я скину в песочницу, глянете?

Comment: ок, давайте, гляну

Comment: @Mikl http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woeEye

Comment: Там высота у блока .slider 69px. Значит дело не в стилях, а в том как этот блок изменяет плагин слайдера, который в примере не подключен.

Comment: @Mikl в том то и дело, что пока плагина нет, только верстку делаю... не знаю почему такое поведение блока...